# How to move a Div over different frames?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have 3 frames in page. I have a div in the 1st frame and I want it to be displayed at the center of page where 2nd frame is there. How do I do this? I can not Put that code in the 2nd frame.

Comment: My question would be: do you really need frames? It's sooooooooo 1995. There are now many better solutions. Havwe you thought about iframes?

Comment: Divs do not cross frames, if you want to show a div in another frame and all pages are from the same server, just use top.otherFrame.document to access the page in that frame

Answer (score 0):

Use 'position: absolute'.

More info **http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp**

Also, do not use frames - not a good idea! Use div's + ajax.

Comment: Website like many others - not always 100% accurate - but in 99.9% cases you get a good example and explanation.

Comment: w3schools is in my experience a LOT less accurate than that. Also very poor examples, especially for newbies.

Comment: I use [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) whenever I need such information - their [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript) documentation is fabulous and seems always up to date. For alternative IE stuff, I use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library) For PHP, I use [php.net](http://php.net)

Answer (score 0):

Divs do not cross frames so you cannot show a div that straddles the frames

If you want to show a div in another frame and all pages are from the same server, just use top.otherFrame.document to access the page in that frame

like

```
var div = top.otherFrame.document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML="Hello";
div.style.position="absolute"; // postioned from 0,0 of the FRAME top left corner
div.style.top="200px";
div.style.left="100px";

top.otherFrame.document.body.appenChild(div);
```